# .htaccess - block request if containts a word (variable)

Tags: .htaccess

I'm getting tons of requests on my site based on an old url (get variable) structure. Its not something humans follow, so instead of redirecting it I want to block it so it uses almost 0 resources from server.

If the url contains something like `thewebsite.com/?s=bla&some_variable=1` I want to block it with prejuduce!

This is what I have but it does not seem to work.

```
<FilesMatch "some_variable=1$">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You could parse query string with *mod_rewrite* and `QUERY_STRING`.

You can put this code in your root htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} some_variable=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Note: don't forget to check if *mod_rewrite* is enabled